# different between CRC8 , CRC16 and CRC32?

Tags: crc

I would like to know the difference and how to choose the polynomial generator for different crc ?

And in some C code they have look up table to compute crc and some of them do it by xor truth table. but in both the cases it is 1byte data array. Its confusing . Could somebody explain this as well ?

Thanks.!

Comment: Read this excellent tutorial: [A PAINLESS GUIDE TO CRC ERROR DETECTION ALGORITHMS](http://www.ross.net/crc/crcpaper.html).